# Access enums from Jar file in Jruby

Tags: java, enums, jruby, jruby-java-interop

I'm trying to access the following static enum

```
public class Colors
{
    public enum ListofColors 
    {
        BLUE, RED, YELLOW
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error

```
NameError: cannot load Java class Colors.Colors::ListofColors::BLUE
```

When I try the following:

```
CL = JavaUtilities.get_proxy_class('Colors.Colors::ListofColors::BLUE')
```

but then I tried the following:

```
CL = JavaUtilities.get_proxy_class('Colors.Colors')
red = Colors.Colors::ListofColors::RED
```

And it gave me the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Colors
```

Is there a different way to get this static enum from the jar file and include it in Jruby without getting that errpr?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need package::class, you repeated Colors twice

also see

[Problems Calling a Java Class from JRuby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396430/problems-calling-a-java-class-from-jruby)

figure out if java_import helps you https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

Also you dont seem to be using the variable CL, Try using

CL::ListofColors::Blue

Comment: My package name is Colors and my Class name is also Colors

Comment: The problem is not with calling the class, the problem is with getting the constant enum Red

Comment: package name with upper case? try using :: ?

Comment: I can call the class, no problem there. The error rises when I try to get the enum Red

Comment: that is not evident from what you have posted so far and you are not even using CL variable

Comment: Any particular reason why your ListofColors enum is inside your class? Maybe it would be easier to reach if it were outside the class.

Comment: @JRSofty I can't control that, I've been given the jar file and I only need to use it in Jruby

Comment: then try CL.new first and then access enum

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Please note that I can call the class (package::class) without any errors. All I need now is to get the enum

Comment: try CL.new().ListofColors.BLUE

Comment: Nested `enum`s are implicitly static, there's no need to explicitly declare them static.

Comment: Thank you everyone, especially @KalpeshSoni. That did not work, but this did: CL::ListofColors::Blue

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Maybe edit your answer so that I can check it as the correct answer? Thanks.